# Server Client Program in Java

Tags: java, client

I'm implementing a program where the controller(server) calls the agent(client) periodically and sends it IP address.

Controller.java

```
public class Controller {
         static int discoveryInterval;
         NetworkDiscovery n1;

   Controller(){        
         discoveryInterval=6000;
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
         Timer t1=new Timer();
         t1.schedule(new NetworkDiscovery(), discoveryInterval);
}
}
```

NetworkDiscovery.java-

```
import java.io.*;
public class NetworkDiscovery extends TimerTask {
        protected DatagramSocket socket = null;
        protected BufferedReader in = null;

        public NetworkDiscovery() throws IOException {
               this("NetworkDiscovery");
        }
public NetworkDiscovery(String name) throws IOException {
        super(name);
        socket = new DatagramSocket(4445);
}

public void run() {
        try {
        byte[] buf = new byte[256];

       // receive request
       DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
       socket.receive(packet);

       // figure out response
       String dString = InetAddress.getLocalHost().toString();
       buf = dString.getBytes();

       // send the response to the client at "address" and "port"
       InetAddress address = packet.getAddress();
       int port = packet.getPort();

       packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length, address, port);
       socket.send(packet);
} catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
}
socket.close();
}
}
```

On the Agent(client's side)-
Agent.java

```
public class Agent {
      ackDiscovery ackDisc=new ackDiscovery();
      public static void main(String[] args) throws  SocketException,UnknownHostException,IOException {
             ackDiscovery ackDisc=new ackDiscovery();
             ackDisc.ackInfo();
             }
}
```

And ackDiscovery.java-

```
public class ackDiscovery {
            int agentListenPort;
            void ackDiscovery(){
                      agentListenPort=4455;
}

public void ackInfo() throws SocketException, UnknownHostException, IOException{
              // get a datagram socket
              DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();

              // send request
              byte[] buf = new byte[256];
              InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(MY_IP);
              DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length, address,      4445);
              socket.send(packet);
              // get response
              packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
              socket.receive(packet);

              // display response
              String received = new String(packet.getData());
              System.out.println("Data received:"+ received);
              socket.close();
}
}
```

When I run the Controller(Server), the Agent's(client's) side get executed only once though the Controller is still listening. Also, if I re-run the agent, nothing happens. Can someone please help me?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).  2) Please use indentation in code.  Indentation helps the readability.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson- Sure, I'll edit it right away.

Comment: Good call on the edit.  Unfortunately: 1) An SSCCE should ideally be a single source file.  2) That is tricky to do with a server/client set-up (but not impossible).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the definitions of the schedule method here:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html

You can see that the method with a single long parameter, will only execute once.
What you're looking for is the one with two long parameters. This will wait for **delay** ms and then execute every **period** ms.

The one you are using will only execute once after **delay** ms.

You may also want to look at either using non-blocking io (java.nio.*) for receiving connections or using a receive timeout. This way you won't have multiple threads running at once.

Comment: It is best to link to the latest version of the JavaDocs.  See [point 2](http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7090875) for tips on how to get that link.

Comment: My bad, didn't realize that was an old link.

Comment: The tip involves finding JavaDoc links using Google.  Did you read it?

Comment: I did read it, but when I first got the link, I was concerned with answering the question, not with how up to date the javadoc was for that class. Classes like these rarely change.

Comment: @xthexder- I implemented scheduleAtFixedRate() on the server's side and need to do the same thing on the client's side too. But how do I synchronise them? Any pointers would be welcome.

Comment: What you can do, is place the server run method in a while loop, and use the same code you posted in the OP. This way the server will be constantly listening, and the client can connect whenever it needs. Since the server is blocking, it won't run any code until it receives a packet.